# Why ExcelWriter is not working from pands library in QGIS Python console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pandas

When I am trying to write excel file using python Pandas library in  QGIS(version 3.12 & 3.10), it is through up error saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'"
How to resolve this issue in QGIS?
When I run my code in QGIS python console, it is showing the error as shown below.
Here my code is

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> writer  = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 18, in __init__
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.12/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 743, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Comment: Have you installed openpyxl?

Comment: Like Anaconda environment there is no such option to install libraries in QGIS, and moreover I didnt get any help for how to install external Libraries (openpyxl) in QGIS in windows.

Comment: https://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com/2018/12/install-third-party-python-modules-in.html

Comment: Thank you, It worked to install openpyxl library through OSGeo4W.

Comment: NOTE: But before installing external libraries if we have any proxy setting to be enabled then use follwing commands

enter prooxy settings > HTTPS_PROXY=https:user_id:user_password@proxy:port_number
enter proxy settings  > HTTP_PROXY=http:user_id:user_password@proxy:port_number